# Mysterious "Will never be executed" warning

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand "Will never be executed" warning here:

```
protocol FatalErrorReporterInterface {

    func fail(_ message: String) -> Never

}

final class FatalErrorReporter: FatalErrorReporterInterface {

    // This line emits "Will never be executed" warning
    func fail(_ message: String) -> Never {
        fatalError(message)
    }

}
```

Yet another compiler bug?

Comment: This is a known bug, see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Jordan Rose @ Swift Evolution mailing list:

> Sure looks like one to me. In particular, it looks like SR-2729.
>
> (I suspect this is because calling the method through the protocol
>   generates a bit of wrapper code that then calls the original method;
>   that wrapper code doesn’t have a location of its own.)
>
> Sorry for the trouble, Jordan

Link:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2729